# How to remotely detach a screen from another terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, gnu-screen, tty

So I have 2 terminals open in front of me;

1. /dev/pts/1  - 'the controller'
2. /dev/pts/2  - 'the receiver'

I am currently using [ttyecho](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/) to execute commands in /pts2 from /pts1.
I can list the screens - `ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 screen -ls` fine from /pts1 and see the results in /pts2.
I can attach to a screen `ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 screen -x [blah]` from /pts1 on /pts2 fine..  But what I can't do, is when attached to a screen then detach from it.

So if /dev/pts/2 is then inside a screen, I am trying to detach from it by executing a command using ttyecho from /dev/pts1

I've tried sending...

```
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 ^a+d  
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 screen -d -r 
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 screen -D -RR
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 screen -d -r
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 screen -DRi
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 Ctrl+a+d
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 Ctrl+a d
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 CTRL + A
ttyecho -n /dev/pts/2 control+a
```

So I guess what I need is either:

- A command I can send that will detach the screen **OR**
- Someway to send some kind of pseudo keyboard commands via `ttyecho` to that other screen to detach it.

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
$ screen -ls
```

This will list all the screen sessions like this.

```
There are screens on:
        8365.pts-6.vm2    (Attached)
        7317.pts-1.vm2    (Attached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

Then you can detach any screen session with the help of screen id.

For eg:

```
$ screen -d 8365
[8365.pts-6.vm2 detached.]
```

Answer (score 3):

There’s no need to use `ttyecho` to detach the `screen` session, you can ask `screen` to do it for you:

```
screen -d pts-2
```

This will detach the session matching the name “pts-2”, which by default would match a screen session started on `pts/2`.

Comment: Genius, easy when you know how. Thanks Stephen