# screen -D -R ... If necessary detach and logout remotely - what is the purpose of "logout remotely" here?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

My current use case passed to me on the job of `screen` usage is `ssh` to server, `su` to technical user account, then `screen -RD`. When `ssh` session is automatically lost due to timeout, I repeat the steps and have my "terminal status" on the server for that technical account looking same as if no connection reset happened.

I wanted to understand importance of `-RD` flags and on [screen man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) I've read (emphasis by me):

> -D -R
>
> Attach here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running,
>   then reattach. If necessary detach and ***logout remotely*** first. If it
>   was not running create it and notify the user. This is the author's
>   favorite.

I've tried web search for `logout remotely screen`, relevant top result was only https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/, where I've read about detaching:

> Detaching a Screen
>
> Just when you want to log out of the remote
>   session, but you want to keep the session you created on that machine
>   alive, then just what you need to do is detach the screen from the
>   terminal so that it has no controlling terminal left. After doing
>   this, you can safely logout.

On SE I've found [How to remotely detach a screen from another terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422949/how-to-remotely-detach-a-screen-from-another-terminal) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/526972/remotely-log-out-of-graphical-gnome-session but these are other specific questions.

I've tried to read wiki on logging in, out etc but it is still not clear. What session can I logout remotely? I'm running `screen` on the server... Maybe these flags are irrelevant in my that specific use case? What is most common use case for `-RD` (remote logout)?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but I think it probably means that if the screen session is currently attached to another SSH session right now, it will detach and logout of that SSH session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `screen` on the server, you actually have two terminal sessions at once: the first one you SSH'd in with, and a second, "local" one that is managed by the `screen` command. If the first session is terminated for any reason without exiting `screen` properly first, these two sessions will automatically separate from each other, and when you establish a new SSH session, `screen` allows you to reconnect to the existing second session.

If the timeout that is cutting off your connections is something like a firewall cutting off an existing connection for inactivity, the problem in that is the firewall may have no method to signal the cut-off to either end of the connection, *until the end in question attempts to send something* over the connection that has been cut off.

So if the firewall cuts off the SSH connection and you then enter even a single character on the SSH connection, the firewall will send back a TCP Reset to the SSH client and you see that the connection has been cut off. *But the SSH server side is  not necessarily aware of it:* if the server has not attempted to send anything to you, it may still be sitting there, waiting for any input from you, on a TCP connection that is -as far as the server knows- still connected but idle.

In this particular case, you'll need the `-D` option in the `screen -DR` to rip off the `screen` session from the old SSH session even if `screen` thinks it is still connected.

As a side effect, it will cause the server to attempt to send output (the "disconnected" message from `screen`, and a new shell prompt) on the initial, cut-off SSH session, the firewall will send a TCP Reset back, and so the `sshd` on server side will finally get the information that the old SSH connection has been interrupted at the network level, and will clean it up.

But if the thing causing your SSH session to time out is something at the server causing your first SSH session to terminate, for example the server administrator setting the `ClientAliveCountMax` to 0 in `sshd_config` and `ClientAliveInterval` to some non-zero value as a hack to get a sort-of inactivity timeout from `sshd`, then your old SSH session will have fully disconnected and the `screen` session will already be waiting for you in an already-separated state. In that case, just `screen -R` would be sufficient to reconnect to it... but additionally specifying the `-D` option won't hurt in this case.

---

By the way, abusing the `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` settings in `sshd_config` that way is a pretty unreliable way to set up an user inactivity timeout, as *the client side can work around it without knowing that they're doing it*. This is because `ClientAliveInterval` is about monitoring activity on the level of the SSH connection, not actual user activity.

If the user of the SSH client is experiencing network timeout issues, they might set `ServerAliveInterval` in their `~/.ssh/config` (or an equivalent setting on a non-OpenSSH client). If the client's `ServerAliveInterval` is set shorter than the firewall's connection inactivity timeout, it would cause the SSH client to automatically send an encrypted SSH "are you still there?" packet on inactivity, and the `sshd` at the server would reply to it, resetting the inactivity timers on the firewall.

But setting a client-side `ServerAliveInterval` with a shorter timeout value would also cause the server to never reach the `ClientAliveInterval` timeout as long as the SSH connection is actually working, defeating the supposed "user inactivity timeout".

Unfortunately some security hardening standard seems to have incorporated this `ClientAliveInterval`-based user inactivity timeout hack, and so some security auditors may require it, even though it's not really fit for its supposed purpose.